# I have to create network controller on Centos 7

Tags: centos7

I have make setup  like controller works in middle on which Centos 7.eth0 of middle controller is connected to Internet.eth1 is connected to laptop/router(LAN).I have to forward traffic from eth0 to eth1.i have to control eth1 traffic from controller .
Problem:I am unable to ping and send traffic from eth0 to eth1??Internet to eth0 is working fine .controller to eth1 is not working??
please Help!!
Thanx

Comment: Kindly Format your Question...

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and configuration are off topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably not have running a DHCP Server on your CentOS machine you should set a static IP for both maschines. On CentOS you can do this using

```
ifconfig eth1 192.168.178.1
```

Then on the other end of eth1 do

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.178.2
```

You may also have to enable IP forwarding on CentOS doing

```
sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ip_v4/ip_forward
```